# How to change the Value in the Shared Preference when i change the quantity of number in Edit text in android

Tags: android, android-layout, sharedpreferences, android-recyclerview

I am trying to change the value in shared Preference when I change the value Quantity of number in Edit Text, but it cannot be replace the value in shared preference instead of stored separately in shared preference.

Code:

```
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


     String qtyString = s.toString();//change the value in editext

     //shared preference    
     sharedPreferences = view.getContext().getSharedPreferences(MYCARTPREFERENCE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     QutId = sharedPreferences.edit();

     // convert into json array to stored in shared preference 
     JSONArray test = new JSONArray();
     JSONArray test1 = new JSONArray();
     JSONArray test2 = new JSONArray();
     JSONArray items = null;
     JSONArray itemsQty = null;
     test1.put("0"); //item id [0,3,2]
     test2.put("0"); // qty id eg[0,1,2]
     test.put(test1);
     test.put(test2); // finally my arry would be like in sahre preference [[0,3,2],[0,1,2]]
     JSONArray listitems = null;
     String Sharedqty = String.valueOf(cartlistadp.get(getAdapterPosition()).getQty()); // i  get qty id from adapter position
     String channel = (shared.getString(Constants.cartid, String.valueOf(test)));
     try {
         listitems = new JSONArray(channel);
         itemsQty = listitems.getJSONArray(1);
     } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     for (int x = 0; x < itemsQty.length(); x++) {
         if (itemsQty.equals(qtyView.getText().toString())) {
             try {
                 listitems.getJSONArray(1).put(qtyString); //  i can stored editext  change value
             } catch (JSONException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }


     }
     QutId.putString(Constants.cartid, (String.valueOf(listitems)));
     QutId.apply();

 }
 }
```

Note: I used this code in `EditText` `TextWatcher`

I can't replace the value,anyone can solve this problem

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using 2 SharedPrefs - shared and QutId?

Comment: I declared like this sharedPreferences=view.getContext().getSharedPreferences(MYCARTPREFERENCE,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            QutId =sharedPreferences.edit(); thats why i used

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] where all variables are defined.

Comment: This should save a shared preference: `sharedPreferences.edit().putString("name-of-string", "value-of-string").apply()` and this `sharedPreference.getString("name-of-string", "default-value-if-no-string-is-found` is used to read that string

Comment: @cricket i edited above per explation

Comment: @Luca  you are right , but i got confused how to replace the corresponding qtyid

Comment: Are you sure `listitems.getJSONArray(1).put(qtyString);` and the code around it is doing what you want?

Comment: that  id can be stored in seperately

Comment: @cricket yes that is quantity id which i want to store but it can be store seperately can't replace that value that is the problem

Comment: I only ask because I assume `Constants.cartid` doesn't change. Therefore if the SharedPreferences aren't updating, then `listitems` is the problem

Comment: constant.cartid doesn't change but i got like this ["0","1","2"] store the value seperately(2 i change from editext) instead of changing

Comment: leave my code i need to replace the  corresponding Qty in shared preference how to do that tell me

Comment: what is Qty? qtyString is the string you want to save right?